# Can GCC modify C headers for C++ features?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

The standard says in section 17.6.1.2 paragraph 4 that:

> Except as noted in Clauses [language.support] through [thread] and
>   Annex [depr], the contents of each header *cname* shall be the same as
>   that of the corresponding header *name.h*, as specified in the C
>   standard library ([intro.refs]) or the C Unicode TR, as appropriate,
>   as if by inclusion.

Then in section 18.2 but paragraph 2:

> The contents are the same as the Standard C library header `<stddef.h>`,
>   with the following changes:

I read this to mean that `<cstddef>` must include `<stddef.h>` unmodified. But GCC has this in their header file:

`/usr/lib/gcc/$TRIPLET/5.3.1/include/stddef.h`

```
#if defined (_STDDEF_H) || defined (__need_NULL)                                                              
#undef NULL     /* in case <stdio.h> has defined it. */                                                       
#ifdef __GNUG__                                                                                               
#define NULL __null                                                                                           
#else   /* G++ */                                                                                             
#ifndef __cplusplus                                                                                           
#define NULL ((void *)0)                                                                                      
#else   /* C++ */                                                                                             
#define NULL 0                                                                                                
#endif  /* C++ */                                                                                             
#endif  /* G++ */                                                                                             
#endif  /* NULL not defined and <stddef.h> or need NULL. */                                                  
#undef  __need_NULL
```

Is this legal by the standard?

Comment: The key question for this kind of issue is always "can you write a conforming program that can tell the difference?"

Comment: C and C++ standard library headers need not be actual files in a filesysyem in your OS that you can open in an editor and look. They are abstract entities defined only by effects of their respective `#include` directives on conforming programs.

Answer (score 1):

The key part of you quote is:

> ...the contents of each header cname shall be the same as that of the corresponding header name.h, as specified in the C standard library ([intro.refs]) or the C Unicode TR...

It's ambiguous in several regards:

- What constitutes "content"?  Is it all the textual file content, or the set of declarations and definitions therein, or only those potentially visible to a particular language (assuming a C program doesn't define `__cplusplus`)?
- Is "as specified" a requirement on the content of cname, or the content of name.h?  If the requirement relates to cname (my interpretation), then there's no restriction there related to name.h content.

With such ambiguity, I don't think there's a definitive answer to your question, but nor can I see a reason to care....

Answer (score 0):

> **Except as noted in Clauses** [language.support] through [thread] and Annex [depr] [...] **as if** by inclusion.

1. I don't see how "as if by inclusion" could be read as meaning "by actual inclusion."
2. §18.2 is part of [language.support], so it's included in the range "[language.support] through [thread]", so it falls under the "Except as noted" clause anyway.